# pyQt: query checkbox checked in a QListWidget

Tags: pyqt, qlistwidget

I am adding Checkboxes to a QlistWidget like this

```
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(listWidget)
ch = QtGui.QCheckBox()
listWidget.setItemWidget(item, ch)
```

like here
[Can't change state of checkable QListViewItem with custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510341/cant-change-state-of-checkable-qlistviewitem-with-custom-widget)

but i am somehow unable to get the checkbox item back at the time i want to know if they are checked by the user. I must be missing something very basic...

```
for index in xrange(listWidget.count()): 
    it=listWidget.itemAt(index,0)
```

So i need to know which checkboxes in the list the user checked?
I cant figure what to do with the returned list item object to get the checkbox state.
Should i use checkbox callbacks instead? Seems easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `itemAt` to get the item.  From the [QListWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistwidget.html#itemAt) docs:

> QListWidgetItem QListWidget.itemAt (self, int ax, int ay)
>
> Returns a pointer to the item at the coordinates (x, y).

You probably want `QListWidget.item()`.  Using that you can loop over the list items and get the check state like this

```
for index in xrange(listWidget.count()):
    check_box = listWidget.itemWidget(listWidget.item(index))
    state = check_box.checkState()
```

Comment: if listwidget is the qlistwidget, what is itemWidget?